# How can I freelance remotely for overseas advertising agencies as a writer? 

Tags: freelance

How can I freelance remotely for overseas advertising agencies as a writer? Is there a site that caters for such a thing?

The idea excites me and as a writer, I'm able to liaise with clients and agencies via email. Do you know of a way to branch out like this? I'm currently involved with the South African advertising industry.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to create a profile on a site such as [Elance](http://www.elance.com/). Once you've done so, you can immediately begin bidding on jobs from clients around the world. This is where I got my start as a freelance writer after college and my first job was for a start-up in Singapore.

However, the vast majority of the jobs posted on these sites offer very poor pay. It's a good place to get experience, but I wouldn't advise relying on it for any kind of serious income.

Another useful site is [Flexjobs](http://www.flexjobs.com), which lists telecommuting jobs, though they charge you for the service.

Finally, there is always the old-fashioned direct approach. Find a client you'd like to work for and reach out to them with a proposal and examples of past work. If your experience is anything like mine, you'll be rejected quite a bit, but you'll learn a lot about dealing with people on the way and when you do get work it will pay much better than about 99% of projects found on bidding sites.